# Connect open and close delimiters with a line

Tags: faces, highlighting, display

I wonder if emacs has something similar to this VSCode extension (Bracket Pair Colorizer 2) which does the following (screenshot below) which I find is a really helpful UI enhancement

[image: Yelllow Line]
[

In the above screenshot, you can see a yellow line that shows the matching parentheses, I know you can get rainbow parentheses but this isn't the same as the screenshot shown. 
Does anyone know if this is possible within emacs and if there's a package to enable it? Or how to enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could something like the [highlight-indent-guides](https://github.com/DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides) package close enough?

Comment: Hi, thank you! That's definitely close enough for me.

Comment: Fair warning though, it can lag, so turn it off by default and toggle it in on/off with a key binding

Comment: Please refer to the [guidelines for providing an answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly to the section "Provide context for links". You can make the answer more useful by adding some context. Thanks for considering!